# Using sed to delete a string including a linebreak within

Tags: sed

I want to use sed to delete a specific string from a file :

> sed -i 's/mystringtodelete//g'

However, this does not work if there are random linebreaks within the string, for example :

> my
>
> strin
>
> gtodel
>
> ete

Does someone know a workaround ?

Comment: Delete the newlines by passing the data through `tr -d '\n'`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that deleting all \n corrupts my file.

Comment: Could you maybe update the example with some real data that shows this?  At the moment, it does not even mention a file.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `s` command’s regexp you need to turn each single newline of your string into a `\n`. That is, like this:

```
s/my\n\nstrin\n\ngtodel\n\nete\n//g
```

Pay attention to the last `\n` in particular, whether it actually has to be part of your pattern or not.

Then, also keep in mind that `sed` is a line-oriented tool, which means that by default it applies commands to each input *line* in turn, and each newline (linebreak) present in its input qualifies as one single “input line”.

Therefore if you need to match a pattern containing newlines you need to explicitly instruct `sed` about that.

One alternative is to use the `-z` option to make it use NUL characters (binary 0x00) as line-delimiter, but this cannot be done if your input data *also* contains NULs.

If your input does *not* contain NULs (and your `sed` actually has the `-z` option) then you can just use the `s` command above with `sed -z` and you’re all set.

The alternative that can work with any input is basically to make `sed` append lines into its so-called “hold space”, and then apply your pattern to that in-memory area.

If you can narrow down your input onto which apply the substitution using `sed`’s addresses, it may be better because some `sed` implementations have limited room for the hold-space. Else you need to read the whole input in, and hope that it will fit into that area. However, GNU’s `sed` for instance has no limit, so if you’re using a common Linux system you should be all right.

Assuming that your input cannot be narrowed down (i.e. your string can appear anywhere in your input), one `sed` command for you might be:

```bsh
cat input_file | sed -ne '1h;1!H;${x;s/my\n\nstrin\n\ngtodel\n\nete\n//g;p}'
```

Breaking down the `sed`’s command for explanation:

```bsh
1h;     # *copy* first line to hold-space
1!H;    # *append* all non-first lines (i.e. all lines after the first) to hold-space
${x;    # at the end of input move hold-space into regular pattern-space
  s/my\n\nstrin\n\ngtodel\n\nete\n//g;  # then apply substitution
  p}    # and print the resulting text
```